# WCF Access is denied with IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7.5, .net-4.5

I created a brand new WCF web application with .NET 4.5.1

I have set in IIS the Authentication to Anonymous Authentication (enabled). All the other options are disabled. The web site in IIS is set to its own application pool which run under my credential. I am the administrator of the machine. The application pool is set to use version 4.

The url is

```
http://localhost:8885/Service1.svc
```

The port is good.

If I use the Process Monitoring I see this output for w3wp.exe:

[image]

[Full Size here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi5rb.png)

Why do I get a 401 error, if I have the read-write access (the app pool is running my account)?

Server Error in '/' Application.
**Access is denied**.
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources.

Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to 'C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyServiceA\MyServiceA\Service1.svc'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it works, you have to create a website in IIS and inside Visual Studio, in the property of the project, you add a virtual directory.

[image]

After, if you go into IIS, you will see an application added to your website.

[image]

From here you can access your WCF services

```
http://localhost:8885/MyServiceA/Service1.svc
```

Comment: Actually it can work even without the virtual folder. I tried your advice and moved it to a virtual folder, it worked, but then I realized that it worked because the virtual directory wasn't taking configuration from my old web.config. The REAL problem was a serviceAuthorization defined in my web.config which called a custom authorization class.